# R Shiny Flexdashboard ValueBox in Column layout

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I need to align some elements in a column layout in a Shinydashboard which combines some elements from flexdashboard. Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    column(3,flexdashboard::valueBoxOutput("ValueBox")),
    #flexdashboard::valueBoxOutput("ValueBox"),
    column(3,plotOutput("plot1",height = 150)),
    column(6,h3("Gauges"),
           fluidRow(
             column(3,flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("Gauge1")),
             column(3,flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("Gauge2"))
             )
           )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$ValueBox <- renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox(
      value = 100,
      subtitle = "Value",
      icon = icon("area-chart"),
      color = "aqua"
    )
  })

  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata
    hist(data)
  })

  output$Gauge1 <- flexdashboard::renderGauge({
    gauge(60, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = "%") 
  })  

  output$Gauge2 <- flexdashboard::renderGauge({
    gauge(25, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = "%") 
  })    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This produces the output where the value box only fills approximately a third of the space designed for it:
[image]

When I change the `valueBoxOutput` to be outside of a `column` (comment out the first and uncomment the second line in the `dashboardBody`), the valuebox does fill the full allocated space, but the "Gauge" output is forced on another line rather than to the right:
[image]

How do I force the "combination" of the two approaches so that the result looks something like this?
[image]

I have tried the following without success:

- Use the `shinydashboard::valueBoxOutput` instead
- Utilize the `width` argument of `column` as well as `valueBoxOutput` commands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After experimenting with column widths based on ismirsehregal's answer, I have discovered what the issue was.

The UI part is correct and both ways are capable of producing the result. The issue was that the definition inside `renderValueBox` did not specify the `width` argument, which was by default set to 4 and represents the relative width compared to the parental environment. Thus, in the first case, the box takes 4/12 of the column of width 3. In the second case, the output had a width of 4+3+6=13, which is higher than 12 and hence was broken into two lines.

The following definition solves the problem:

```
  output$ValueBox <- renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox(
      value = 100,
      subtitle = "Value",
      icon = icon("area-chart"),
      color = "aqua",
      width = 12
    )
  })
```

The `width = 12` sets the box to fill out the whole width of the parental environment, which in this case is a column of width 3. One can also use `width = 3` directly and drop out the `column` definition, but the first way is preferred as the width of all three elements is specified in the UI rather than the server.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    flexdashboard::valueBoxOutput("ValueBox", width = "100%"), # Edit %
    #flexdashboard::valueBoxOutput("ValueBox"),
    column(4,plotOutput("plot1",height = 150)),
    column(4,h3("Gauges"),
           fluidRow(
             column(6,flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("Gauge1")),
             column(6,flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("Gauge2"))
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$ValueBox <- renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox(
      value = 100,
      subtitle = "Value",
      icon = icon("area-chart"),
      color = "aqua"
    )
  })

  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata
    hist(data)
  })

  output$Gauge1 <- flexdashboard::renderGauge({
    gauge(60, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = "%") 
  })  

  output$Gauge2 <- flexdashboard::renderGauge({
    gauge(25, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = "%") 
  })    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So here is the preferred way based on Radek Janhuba's insights - setting the appropriate width while rendering (for everyone going here later):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    column(4,flexdashboard::valueBoxOutput("ValueBox")),
    column(4,plotOutput("plot1",height = 150)),
    column(4,h3("Gauges"),
           fluidRow(
             column(6,flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("Gauge1")),
             column(6,flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("Gauge2"))
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$ValueBox <- renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox(
      value = 100,
      subtitle = "Value",
      icon = icon("area-chart"),
      color = "aqua",
      width = 12
    )
  })

  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata
    hist(data)
  })

  output$Gauge1 <- flexdashboard::renderGauge({
    gauge(60, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = "%") 
  })  

  output$Gauge2 <- flexdashboard::renderGauge({
    gauge(25, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = "%") 
  })    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but has the unfortunate property that one cannot in any way change the width of the box - according to help, the "100" should mean that it will be 100px wide, but changing it to a "1000" or "10%" does not do anything. However, because you needed to change the column widths, I have figured out a way. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry should have been "100%" (got lost on fiddling around..) or 4 does the same.